# Read operation on a BLE characteristic in windows UWP returns a max buffer of 20 bytes

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

*Background:* I have a custom Bluetooth embedded C app on a STM32 Bluetooth module. The application has multiple services each having multiple characteristics of varying lengths.
I'm writing a C# PC application using the UWP Bluetooth platform to connect and read from the embedded device.
*Problem statement:* The C# app reads only buffers with length up to 20 bytes. I have some characteristics that send more than 20 bytes of data.

*Tried:*I have verified that the embedded app is indeed sending the appropriate lengths of buffer via a phone ST app and in debug mode. They do have the correct values.

Code snippet:

```
try
            {
                // BT_Code: read the value from the buffer to the characteristic.
                //GattReadResult result = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();
                GattCommunicationStatus status = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                        GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    CharData.Text = "Read Unsucessfull:";
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CharData.Text = $"Error while reading: {ex}\n";
            }
```

```
void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender,
                                    GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            
        CharData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => CharData.Clear())) ;
        // An Indicate or Notify reported that the value has changed.
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue);
        byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
        reader.ReadBytes(input);
}
```

Comment: Characteristic hanges notification can not be longer than current PDU/MTU size. So it looks like your device has PDU size of 20 bytes (21 actually).

Comment: On the embedded side, my max buffer size is 128 bytes. I have also put my embedded side on DEBUG mode and verified that the buffers get updated appropriately. I have used a ST phone application to verify and it receive the correct length of buffer values. This issue is only on the C# side.

Comment: What is the ATT_MTU of the remote device?

Comment: What is value of MaxPduSize Session property? Also try to use indication instead. Just tested on 2 Windows PCs - no issue. Also tested on ESP32 - also all works as expected.

Comment: The Max PDU size is 23. Can I change/increase this ?